# Visual studio 2015 Error List API

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I'm researching on creating a Visual Studio 2015 extension for code analysis, The extension should display code analysis results in Visual Studio  Error List. I found similar implementation of VS error list in Telerik JustCode extension. Is  there an API to create custom error lists in Visual Studio Extension framework?

Sample UIs,

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

[Telerik JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode/code-analysis-and-error-check.aspx)